# Can anyone explain the Service setForeground method?

Tags: android, service

I'd like to know more about the `setForeground()` method in the `Service` class.

Can any one explain it in detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setForeground()` is deprecated, and I think simply does not work on newer versions of Android. You want the newer `startForeground()` instead.

Quoting myself from [one of my books](http://commonsware.com/Android):

> However, some services will be missed
>   by the user if they mysteriously
>   vanish. For example, the default music
>   player application that ships with
>   Android uses a service for the actual
>   music playback. That way, the user can
>   listen to music while continuing to
>   use their phone for other purposes.
>   The service only stops when the user
>   goes in and presses the stop button in
>   the music player activity. If that
>   service were to be shut down
>   unexpectedly, the user might wonder
>   what is wrong.
>
> Services like this can declare
>   themselves as being part of the
>   "foreground". This will cause their
>   priority to rise and make them less
>   likely to be bumped out of memory. The
>   trade-off is that the service has to
>   maintain a `Notification`, so the user
>   knows that this service is claiming
>   part of the foreground. And, ideally,
>   that `Notification` provides an easy
>   path back to some activity where the
>   user can stop the service.
>
> To do this, in `onCreate()` of your
>   service (or wherever else in the
>   service's life it would make sense),
>   call `startForeground()`. This takes a
>   `Notification` and a locally-unique
>   integer, just like the `notify()` method
>   on `NotificationManager`. It causes the
>   `Notification` to appear and moves the
>   service into foreground priority.
>   Later on, you can call
>   `stopForeground()` to return to normal
>   priority.

Comment: yep, [Service.setForeground() is now deprecated and in 2.0 does nothing](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/02/service-api-changes-starting-with.html).